How to trigger method on button click in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages?
I am developing a web application using ASP.NET Core Razor Pages. I want to trigger a Logout method when clicking a button on the page and redirect the user to the login page. However, the Logout method is not being triggered when I click the button.
Here is my current implementation:
Index.cshtml.cs
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            Username = User.Identity.Name;
        }
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostLogoutAsync()
    {
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        return RedirectToPage("Login");
    }
}

Index.cshtml
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<h1>Welcome</h1>

@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <p>Hello, @Model.Username!</p>
    <form method="post" asp-page-handler="Logout">
        <input type="submit" value="Logout" />
    </form>
}

Problem:
Clicking the "Logout" button does not trigger async Task OnPostLogoutAsync/Logout/OnPostLogout method. How can I ensure the method is correctly triggered when the button is clicked?
Thanks for any suggestions or help!
Ensuring the form's method attribute is set to post.
Ensuring the asp-page-handler attribute is set to the correct handler name.
Program.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.ConfigureFilter(new IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
});

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = "/Login";
        options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    });
var app = builder.Build();
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapRazorPages();
app.Run();

Full project code:
Github source zip file
==== Solved ====
Found out the problem thanks to @MdFaridUddinKiron
I took a look at my Network request, there's no handler=Logout anywhere. So I added action="/Index?handler=Logout" on my form and it worked. I don't feel this is the right way of doing it but it worked.
<form method="post" action="/Index?handler=Logout">
    <input type="submit" value="Logout" asp-page-handler="Logout"/>
</form>

And by adding formaction="?handler=Logout" in the input button also works (so that I can trigger different functions within the same form)
<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Logout" asp-page-handler="Logout" formaction="?handler=Logout" />
</form>


I think  asp-page-handler="Logout" is correct, I have tested using your scenario and code which hitting the action accordingly.

How's your program.cs file looks like? Are there any middleware runnng within your program.cs pipeline?

what response do you get? what status code?

@MdFaridUddinKiron
The only function works is 'Task OnPost()'
Program.cs like :
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
{
options.Conventions.ConfigureFilter(new IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
});
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCookie(....);
var app = builder.Build();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapRazorPages();
app.Run();

@BenderBoy No response, like, nothing but page flashed (like rerender).

What version of asp.net core you are using?

Update your question with full program.cs files you currently have. Also what type of project have you taken Razor page app right?

I just tested with your program.cs file was well its working without any issue. So program.cs file is also correct. Do you have any route configuration?

@MdFaridUddinKiron No route configuration I think? Its an empty project and all I created was these 3 files, didn't touch anything else.
Framework is .Net8

Its a razor page app right? See the screenshot in my answer. Apart from that, why aren't you using app.UseStaticFiles(); which is missing

@MdFaridUddinKiron I have uploaded the source code as a zip file on github.


I want to trigger a Logout method when clicking a button on the page
and redirect the user to the login page. However, the Logout method is
not being triggered when I click the button

Based on your shared code snippet and description, I have investigated the scenario and successfully test your issue.
According to my test, It seems your code is correct and Its hitting the endpoint as expected.
I think, there's something else which has not been shared, it might be middeware pipe line or anything. Please double check that.
Here is the complete code, I have used to reproduced your issue:


Index.cshtml.cs (Page Model):
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

    public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public string Username { get; set; }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            Username = User.Identity.Name;
        }
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostLogoutAsync()
    {
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        return RedirectToPage("Login");
    }
}

Index.cshtml (View):
@page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<h1>Welcome</h1>

<form method="post" asp-page-handler="Logout">
    <input type="submit" value="Logout" />
</form>

Note: I didn't have any authentication schema in my project so for the sake of testing I haven't used User.Identity.IsAuthenticated checkings.
Program.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = "/Login";
    });

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();


Note: Using your program.cs file
Output:



Note: Keep in mind, I have redirected to Privacy page during my test as I don't have login page. As you can see the browser log and network trace its redirecting to that page as expected. In addition, please refer to this official document for more details about asp-page-handler

I copied your code, and I had to add
.AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>{ options.Conventions.ConfigureFilter(new IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());});
In my program.cs,
Otherwise it will show
Http 400 Error
And
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'classList') at HTMLDocument.onDocumentLoad ((index):2940:19)
With that, the issue exist...

What's that ClassList? I have also tried with your program.cs and working fine. Could you take the project picture the way I did, and attached within the question.
